# OpenSSL s_client - handshake failure [SSL3_READ_BYTES]

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

We are trying to establish an `SSL-Connection` from one server to another, to perform some HTTP-Request over a secure connection.

The server that listens for the connection is configured to listen on `Port 5050` and have the Root-Certificate provided to check the `client` certificate for validation.

The `client` wants to connect to this server using the following command:

```
openssl s_client -msg -ssl3 -cert /path/to/cert/clientname.crt -certform PEM -key /path/to/key/clientname.pem -connect server:5050
```

This connect is responding like this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
>>> SSL 3.0 Handshake [length 0086], ClientHello
    01 00 00 82 03 00 54 11 68 42 03 ef 07 59 ff cc
    31 03 99 2c 70 7c 56 fb 08 e3 fc 6a 88 ef 1c 69
    84 fc 26 fc 80 f7 00 00 5a c0 14 c0 0a 00 39 00
    38 00 88 00 87 c0 0f c0 05 00 35 00 84 c0 12 c0
    08 00 16 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a c0 13 c0 09 00
    33 00 32 00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 0e c0 04 00
    2f 00 96 00 41 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00
    04 00 15 00 12 00 09 00 14 00 11 00 08 00 06 00
    03 00 ff 02 01 00
<<< SSL 3.0 Alert [length 0002], fatal handshake_failure
    02 28
140628594931368:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1258:SSL alert number 40
140628594931368:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1410426946
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

In the log of the `SSL-Server`, I got the following entry:

```
INFO connection accepted from clientname:45344

2014-09-11 11:15:46 ERROR SSL error, SSL_ERROR_SSL: retval -1, no shared cipher
```

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

> no shared cipher

Your client is only offering ciphers which the server does not support.
Please try again without the `-ssl3` argument to let the client use newer ciphers.